Include function does not work in EF Core when I inject the generic repository
I implemented this pattern so many times before, I created a context, after that I created a generic repository, like this:
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
 where T : BaseDomain
 {
     private readonly FitnessAppContext _dbContext;

     public GenericRepository(FitnessAppContext dbContext)
     {
         _dbContext = dbContext;
     }

     public async Task Create(T entity)
     {
         await _dbContext.AddAsync(entity);
         _dbContext.SaveChanges();
     }

     public async Task Delete(Guid id)
     {
         _dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(id)).Delete();
         _dbContext.SaveChanges();
     }

     public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
     {
         return _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(a => a.IsDeleted.Equals(false)).AsQueryable();
     }

     public async Task<T> GetById(Guid id)
     {
         var entity = await _dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id.Equals(id) && a.IsDeleted.Equals(false));
         return entity;
     }

     public async Task Update(T entity)
     {
         _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
         await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     }

     public async Task<DbSet<T>> GetSet()
     {
         return _dbContext.Set<T>();
     }

     public IQueryable<T> GetByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
     {
         return _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable().Where(a=>a.IsDeleted.Equals(false)).AsQueryable();
     }

     public async Task ModifyAndSave()
     {
         await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
}

And then I injected my interface like this
private readonly IGenericRepository<Customer> _customerGenericRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Training> _trainingGenericRepository;
public FitnessAppQuery(IGenericRepository<Customer> customerGenericRepository,
    IGenericRepository<Training> trainingGenericRepository)
{
    _customerGenericRepository = customerGenericRepository;
    _trainingGenericRepository = trainingGenericRepository;
}

In in my logic layer when I try to use the getSet() method, in order to use .Include of EF Core, it does not work, it gets the data I want but does not get the included (joined) objects, shows me as null when I look at it by debug tools
public async Task<ListTrainingOutputModel> ListAllTraining()
{
     var outputModel = new ListTrainingOutputModel();
     var trainingSet = await _trainingGenericRepository.GetSet();
     var trainingswithincluded = trainingSet.Include(a => a.TrainingType).ToList();

     try
     {
         //var trainings = _trainingRepository
         //    .GetAllTrainingsWithTrainer();
             //.Select(x => new TrainingListItem
             //{
             //    Id = x.Id,
             //    CourseTime = x.TrainingTime,
             //    CourseTitle = x.TrainingName,
             //    TrainerNameSurname = x.PersonalTrainer.Name + " " + x.PersonalTrainer.Surname
             //});

         //outputModel.Data = trainings.ToList();
         outputModel.IsSuccess = true;
         outputModel.StatusMessage = "Trainings listed successfully";
         return outputModel;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         outputModel.Data = null;
         outputModel.IsSuccess = false;
         outputModel.StatusMessage = ex.ToString();
         return outputModel;
     }
}

My program.cs is like this:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FitnessAppContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITrainingService, TrainingService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFitnessAppQuery, FitnessAppQuery>();
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

I took a look lots of documentations and tried to ask AI tools but did not help.
UPDATE
I found the mistake that I made here
I used
"using Microsoft.System.Data;"s include() function
instead of
"using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" include()
so I changed to the second one given above and the problem was solved

No obvious reason can be seen in what you have shown. So the answer probably is in your entity model / configuration. Either include the relevant parts in the question, or look at the model attributes and/or fluent configuration if the problematic navigation is configured to be excluded from the model (e.g. [NotMapped] attribute, Ignore call), because this is the typical mistake I've seen (people trying to resolve json serialization issues by breaking their entity model). Another thing to check s if your nav property is initialized with new ,,,,  but it won't be null in such case.

Generic Repository abstractions are an anti-pattern with EF. EF already provides a generic repository in the form of DbSet<T>.  If you want an abstraction over EF to make things like testing easier, or enforce core rules like your soft-delete "IsDeleted" then you can introduce a thin Repository wrapper that leverages EF's IQueryable. Still, avoid Generics as tying repositories per-entity is pointless. For something like satisfying SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) the Entity is not the responsibility (actor), the consumer of the repository is the actor.
public interface IFitnessQueryRepository
{
    IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers();
    IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomerById(int customerId);
    IQueryable<Training> GetTrainings();
    IQueryable<Training> GetTrainingById(int trainingId);
}

public class FitnessQueryRepository(AppDbContext _context) : IFitnessQueryRepository
{
    private IFitnessQueryRepository This => this;

    IQueryable<Customer> IFitnessQueryRepository.GetCustomers()
    {
        var query = _context.Customers
            .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        return query;
    }
    IQueryable<Customer> IFitnessQueryRepository.GetCustomerById(int customerId)
    {
        var query = This.GetCustomers()
            .Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
        return query;
    }
    IQueryable<Training> IFitnessQueryRepository.GetTrainings()
    {
        var query = _context.Trainings
            .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        return query;
    }
    IQueryable<Training> IFitnessQueryRepository.GetTrainingById(int trainingId)
    {
        var query = This.GetTrainings()
            .Where(x => x.TrainingId == trainingId);
        return query;
    }
}

The "...ById" are optional, just a commonly used pattern. Returning IQueryable means the consumer has control over additional filtering, sorting, pagination, projection, any eager loading, and even whether to perform the reads synchronously or asynchronously. The "repository" is a thin abstraction which enforces our core rules and provides a nice boundary to mock for unit tests.
What I don't recommend is trying to use a repository abstraction to try and "hide" EF from the consuming code. If you start trying to implement custom filtering with expressions those expressions and such still need to conform to EF rules, so it is a lot of work, potential bugs, and "gotchas" for no benefit. I also do not recommend using Generic repository abstractions, even with IQueryable as Generics are meant for situations where all participating types are treated identically. If your schema has different types for PKs, or something like a composite PK, generics break. The EF team has already put in the hard yards to make a generic repository available in the form of the DbSet<T>. Also having a repository abstraction per entity simply means initializing and passing several dependencies, and mocking those dependencies in tests, rather than dealing with a single repository abstraction under test.  It might "itch" thinking that multiple repositories might have a "GetCustomers()" method that all essentially do the same thing, but having each consumer use a CustomerRepository violates SRP as a single CustomerRepository referenced by 5 services has 5 potentially competing requirements and 5 reasons to change. Reusing such simple code for the sake of DRY is far less important than SRP.

How this answers OP concrete question/issue?

Because their attempt at abstraction with GetSet(), GetByFilter(), and GetById() are completely unnecessary, and likely resulting in details that trip EF up vs. working with IQueryable.  There is no rationale behind making GetSet() async, and even GetById() is pointless as they wouldn't be able to use Include() there either. The OP is painting themselves in a corner attempting to abstract EF, so they should take a step back and simplify rather than adding more code to try and get the abstraction working.
